# Can't get MySQLDb to work in python on Mac is there other easier DB?

Tags: python, mysql, database, database-connection

I am looking for a production database to use with python/django for web development.  I've installed MySQL successfully.  I believe the python connector is not working and I don't know how to make it work.  Please point me in the right direction.  Thanks.

If I try importing `MySQLdb`:

```
import MySQLdb
```

I get the following exception.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vantran/tutorial/scrape_yf/mysql.py", line 3, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

I've tried using MySQL but I am struggling with getting the connector package to install or work properly.  http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=414340

I've also tried to look at the other SO questions regarding installing MySQL  python connectors, but they all seem to be unnecessarily complicated.

I've also tried

1. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm
2. http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/
3. https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL

...but nothing seems to work.

Comment: If you're just asking for a recommendation, that's really not a good fit for SO. Why not instead explain the exact problem you're having with `MySQLdb`, and ask for help with that?

Comment: I've revised the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is with the `MySQLdb` module, not the MySQL server itself, you might want to consider [`PyMySQL`](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) instead. It's much simpler to set up. Of course it's also somewhat different.

The key difference is that it's a pure Python implementation of the MySQL protocol, not a wrapper around `libmysql`. So it has minimal requirements, but in a few use cases it may not be as performant. Also, since they're completely different libraries, there are a few rare things that one supports but not the other, and various things that they support differently. (For example, `MySQLdb` handles all MySQL warnings as Python warnings; `PyMySQL` handles them as information for you to process.)

Comment: I had to install "setuptools"  using $sudo easy_install setuptools.  And the rest works like a charm.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend postgres.app : http://postgresapp.com

Tried and never left

My preference for the driver is http://initd.org/psycopg/

You'll find a list of drivers at http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Python

Comment: I will read up on postgres.  It's new to me.  Could you you give me links to a few tutorial or video tutorials? The ones on youtube are fragmented.  I'm really excited to get a quick crash course on postgres. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't have a tutorial to reccomend, probably I would google it. If you are familiar with SQL and RDBMS you should feel at home. The good part of Postgres.APP is that you'll find a self-contained package with all you need to develop on a production ready db but usable on a dev machine like your Mac. Start here : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks for the links to some tutorial docs.  I found postgres website to be really useful, too.